# Tests not running using the 'surefire' plugin for Maven

Tags: java, testng, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using TestNG to run my tests in Eclipse. I have set up the maven-surefire-plugin in my pom.xml file. 
On running 'mvn clean install', I get this error and and the tests don't run. Even when I manually try to run the tests in Eclipse using TestNG, the tests get skipped and don't run. Not sure what the issue is.

[image: On running 'mvn clean install'[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKYuI.jpg)

Comment: whats in the suite xml file? whats the error ?

Comment: I have attached two images. The command line picture shows the error for the failed build.

Comment: it appears that `${TestSuite}` is undefined in your project

Comment: Your test suite isn't defined. How are you passing in your test suite? I would expect something along the following:
mvn test -DTestSuite=somefile.xml

Answer (score 0):

most likely you have to specify your testng.xml (the real file that stands for ${TestSuite} parameter) as the **Template XML file** as described here:

http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-listeners

[image]